# Why are Heroku errors messages H12 timeout and 'internal server error' appearing upon deployment, when no issues experienced on local host?

Tags: heroku, timeout, internal-server-error

Upon deploying website on Heroku, error code H12 (timeout) is encountered when clicking on 'blog' page link (all other links are fine), and 'internal server error' appears when submitting forms. No issues experienced when testing on local host.

Github code: https://github.com/Louisrobertson20/bluebrew

Comment: Share the deployed Heroku website. It tells you why it fails when you open console (F12 or ctrl+shift+i)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Heroku site: https://desolate-fjord-95461.herokuapp.com/

I'm seeing error codes 500 and 503.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue - the congif vars inside Heroku were set incorrectly.